# how to link dependency libraries with makefile

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Dependency Libraries: `libxml >= 2.7.6 openssl >= 0.9.8` Digital Signature Generation requires an additional libraries: `libXslt >= 1.1.24 libxmlsec1 >= 1.2.9`

These are Dependency library. i have project code but for running the makefile required dependency libraries.

I have downloaded these libraries and copy into `usr/include` folder then installed. 
but i dont know the exact way how to add in makefile these dependency library... 
i m using ubuntu 11.04.

```
#GCC compiler

CC=gcc
CFLAGS= -D__XMLSEC_FUNCTION__=__FUNCTION__ -DXMLSEC_NO_XSLT=1 -DXMLSEC_NO_XKMS=1 -I/usr/include/libxml2 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO_DYNAMIC_LOADING=1 -DXMLSEC_CRYPTO=\"openssl\" -DUNIX_SOCKETS -DXML_SECURITY -DDEBUG -I/usr/include/protobuf-c-0.15  -L/usr/include/libxslt-1.1.24
LDFLAGS= -lcrypto -I/usr/include/libxml2 -lxml2     -I/usr/include/xmlsec1 -lxmlsec1 -lprotobuf-c       
LIBS=-lm

fileClient:                 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)  $(LIBS) src/main.c src/file2.c src/file3.pb-c.c -o fileClient   

clean:
        $(RM)   fileClient  *.o *~  


        #
```

Comment: Do not copy headers manually. You should install the respective dev packages instead. They install the necessary headers for you. For example, `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that in the `Makefile` but in some of your header with code like

```
#if LIXML_VERSION < 20800
#error too old version of libxml need 2.8.0 or newer 
#endif
```

and you may be interested in `autotools` (`autoconf`, `automake` and friends) and in `pkg-config`

Also, dependency management is best handled by making a `.deb` package. (so you want an Ubuntu package like `libxml2-dev`)